# RefreshMode.ClientWins with multiple users, what happens?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So this is quite the simple question I did not manage to find an answer to yet.
So the situation is as follows:

- User1 initializes an objectcontext
- User2 initializes another objectcontext of the same type
- User1 changes entity A
- User2 changes entity B
- User2 saves changes
- User1 does a refresh with RefreshMode.ClientWins and proceeds to save changes

So what happens with entity B? User1 has not changed it, but it differs from the version in database. My gut would say that because User1 has not made any changes to entity B, it would stay in the state that User2 left it at. But alas I'm not sure and thus I'm asking someone who knows better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is correct - nothing will happen to entity B because there were no changes in the database so the refresh did nothing.

Object context internally tracks two sets of values for every tracked entity - original and current values. Original values are values loaded from the database and current values are actual values modified by your application after loading the entity.

When you call `Refresh` with `ClientWins` mode the context will query the database for the entity, updates all original values in the tracked record for the entity and updates current values which were not changed yet by your application - values which were already changes are not updated (that is the client wins refresh).

When you execute `SaveChanges` EF will detect changes by comparing original values and current values and create update command only for changed columns. `ClientWins` refresh mode is used in scenarios with optimistic concurrency to force overwriting of database changes by new values.

Answer (score 3):

`RefreshMode.ClientWins` only affects whether local changes are preserved. If there are no local changes, there is no difference between `RefreshMode.ClientWins` and `RefreshMode.StoreWins`.

I see that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx) is slightly confusing:

> The StoreWins mode means that the object should be updated to match the data source values. The ClientWins value means that only the changes in the object context will be persisted, even if there have been other changes in the data source.

Non-changes in the object context aren't persisted with `RefreshMode.ClientWins`, but the documentation doesn't clearly say so.